# workflow fires without meeting criteria

Tags: apex, visualforce, workflow, custom-field

i have a workflow and it fires only when **custom_field__c** is not null.
an ETL job runs periodically, then this **custom_field__c** is updating, then the workflow rule fires, i get a email. 
Surprisingly, when i get the email, i dont have that **data** in **custom_field__c** neither in the email, nor on the record(Lead). 
what possibly happening ?? anybody has any idea ?

Comment: can u post us the workflow rule criteria you used ? also can u check the logs / output of ETL to see what value being passed in to that field..

Comment: there are three fields, based on country, custom_field__c , And a checkbox. rule: Evaluate the rule when a record is created, and any time it’s edited to subsequently meet criteria. And i dont know how to check the etl logs. :( and it is not in my control.

Comment: What is the formula or criteria you are using for the rule?

Comment: @ThomasTaylor , this is what i m using. Evaluate the rule when a record is created, and any time it’s edited to subsequently meet criteria.

Comment: Below that, you either indicate a series of criteria, or write a formula that has to evaluate to TRUE. You suggested that it involves 3 fields. But what are the criteria or formula for those fields exactly?